# How to mock a Python class that is two imports deep?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

How can I mock a Python class that's two imports deep, without changing code in either of the imported modules? Say I'm importing a library of web utilities, which imports an HTTPClient() - how can I write a unit test, that mocks the HTTPClient to return a value, without changing the file web_utils.py? I want to use the data manipulation in DataHandler (rather than mock *it* out), but I don't want the HTTPClient to actually connect to the web.

Is this even possible? Given that Python has monkey-patching, it certainly seems like it should be. Or is there an alternative/better way? I'm still figuring out the mocking process, much less changing imports.

```
# someLib/web_utils.py
from abc.client import SomeHTTPClient # the class to replace

def get_client():
    tc = SomeHTTPClient(endpoint='url') # fails when I replace the class
    return tc

class DataHandler(object):
    def post_data(someURL, someData):
        newData = massage(someData)
        client = get_client()
        some_response = client.request(someURL, 'POST', newData)
        return some_response

# code/myCode.py
from someLib.web_utils import DataHandler

dh = DataHandler()
reply = dh.post_data(url, data)

# tests/myTests.py
from django.test.testcases import TestCase
from mock import Mock

class Mocking_Test(TestCase):
    def test_mock(self):
        from someLib import web_utils
        fakeClient = Mock()
        fakeClient.request = web_utils.SomeHTTPClient.request # just to see if it works
        web_utils.SomeHTTPClient = fakeClient
        dh = DataHandler()
        reply = dh.post_data(url='somewhere', data='stuff')
```

Update - added the `get_client()` function. I think @spicavigo's answer is on the right track - it does appear to be replacing the `SomeHTTPClient` class. But for some reason the class doesn't instantiate an object (the error is, "must be type, not Mock"). I don't see how it could, either, being a `Mock()` object that has been created, rather than a class. So I'm not sure how to make that part work.

Comment: Note - I tried `fakeClient.return_value = fakeClient` - it sounded like this would work, so when `tc = SomeHTTPClient(endpoint='url')` was called, the Mock object would return a copy of itself. Didn't seem to work, alas.

Answer (score 4):

Could you add this to myTest.py and try

```
from someLib import web_utils
web_utils.SomeHTTPClient = <YOUR MOCK CLASS>
```

Comment: This has possibilities. I don't have it working yet, but it does appear to be replacing the class. (The problem I'm now having, is an error "unable to process request - must be type, not Mock").

Answer (score 2):

Here's what finally worked:

```
class Mocking_Test(TestCase):
    def test_mock(self):
        def return_response(a, b, c, *parms, **args):
            print "in request().return_response"
            class makeResponse(object):
                status = 200
                reason = "making stuff up"
            return makeResponse()

        fakeClient = Mock()
        fakeClient.return_value = return_response

        #with patch('abc.client.SomeHTTPClient') as MockClient: # not working.
        with patch('abc.client.SomeHTTPClient.request', new_callable=fakeClient):
            dh = DataHandler()
            reply = dh.post_data(url='somewhere', data='stuff')
```

I was on the right track in my original post, with the `patch`, I simply wasn't doing the patching *correctly*. Also, rather than replacing the entire class, I'm replacing just the `request` function on the class (which is all that needs to be mocked out, to avoid actually making an HTTP request).

Answer (score -1):

I know this isn't exactly what you wanted, but after creating your mock class I would simply do something like this, to make the code more clean (in the bash shell, otherwise if you have 1 file you could just do a find and replace)

```
find . -name "*.py" -type f -exec sed -i "s/<old_class>/<mock_class>/g" '{}' \;
```

That should replace all instances of your old class with your new class, and I personally think it would make for much cleaner code. If you want just one file, instead of all .py files, just change -name to "file.py"

Comment: Ah, the point of mocking is *not* to change the original code. Just to temporarily replace some sections, for unit testing.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant as a permenant solution. Sorry.